# WWW domain loads but not without

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, domain, vps

I have set up a VPS with Apache web server, and installed Let's Encrypt for the website.

However, when the site is loaded without the `www.` it goes to the default page from the domain registrar. The website loads correctly if it is included.

I will include my DNS settings below also.

Here are the two links to see the problem live

[www.magiccompetitions.com](https://magiccompetitions.com)

[magiccompetitions.com](http://magiccompetitions.com)

[image: Image of DNS Settings on Domain Registrar]

I have a feeling this is a problem with my DNS settings. However fail to see where the downfall is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate entries for ORIGIN `@` (load balancing method called [Round-robin DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/round-robin-dns/)):

```
magiccompetitions.com.     14400  IN     A     67.209.116.138
magiccompetitions.com.     14400  IN     A     94.136.40.51
```

whereas the subdomain www only has one:

```
www.magiccompetitions.com. 14400  IN     A     67.209.116.138
```

This means that it works for everyone who gets the IP `67.209.116.138` of your VPS, but shows the placeholder page for everyone who gets the `94.136.40.51`, instead.

Remove the line with `@  A  94.136.40.51`, and you might also want to remove the `*  A  94.136.40.51` in order to stop promoting your registrar with every non-existent subdomain like http://wildcard.magiccompetitions.com/

Comment: Also, remove those `CNAME` records; they doesn't seem effective, but the naked domain shouldn't have `CNAME` records as they replace any other record types, including `NS` records.

Answer (score 0):

I get to see your website with both links. One encrypted and the other not but that's not the issue you describe. Maybe you just set the DNS entries and they have not been promoted to the DNS your location is using, yet... Might take a while.

Comment: I can see the site from https://www.magiccompetitions.com/